# nov.el follow link to .epub in other window instead of having a new buffer in the same window

Tags: org-link, doom

When I try to follow a link `[[nov:path/to/epub/ebook.epub][link]]` in `nov-mode` (defined in [nov.el](https://depp.brause.cc/nov.el/)) under Doom Emacs, it always opens the file on a new buffer, replacing the `org` file where the link sits where I keep my notes, which is a nuisance and a major disruption to my reading.

This behavior doesn't change even after customizing my `org-link-frame-setup` to:

```elisp
(org-link-frame-setup
   '((vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
     (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder-other-frame)
     (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
     (file . find-file-other-window)
     (wl . wl-other-frame)))
```

I tried tracing the functions `+org/dwim-at-point` and `org-open-at-point` but couldn't find a way to tweak this behavior.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was changing `org-link-parameters` using the `org-link-set-parameters` function and swapping out the link opening function with your own.

```lisp
;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61949
(defun org-nov-open-new-window (path)
  "Open nov.el link in a new window"
  (setq available-windows
        (delete (selected-window) (window-list)))
  (setq new-window
        (or (car available-windows)
            (split-window-sensibly)
            (split-window-right)))
  (select-window new-window)
  (nov-org-link-follow path))

(org-link-set-parameters "nov" :follow #'org-nov-open-new-window)
```

If you're curious, you can see my nov.el configuration in at [>>>/g/85988659](https://desuarchive.org/g/thread/85976853/#85988659).  Stock nov.el is very plain, so it needs a little configuration love to make the epub reading experience more pleasant.  A nice font and a little margin go a long way.